# Nunjucks within loop, convert attribute to int and sort by int?

Tags: int, jinja2, nunjucks

I have an object:

```
[
  {
   "block": "1",
   ...
   "block": "2",
   ...
   "block": "11"
```

and I want to sort on block as an integer, not as a string (which sorts 1, 11, 2):

```
<!-- sorts as string -->
{% for standard in standards | sort(false, true, 'standard.block') %}
```

I tried to convert `standard.block` to an `int` with no effect

```
{% for standard in standards | sort(false, true, '{{ standard.block | int }}') %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can [see](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/master/nunjucks/src/filters.js#L451): `nunjucks` sorts elements with string comparator (default js behaviour). So you should convert `block`-property to Number before sorting or use a custom filter e.g. `sortBy`

```
const nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
const env = nunjucks.configure();
env.addFilter('sortBy', function (arr, prop) {
    const isNum = val => val == +val;
    const sorter = (a, b) => isNum(a[prop]) && isNum(b[prop]) ? +a[prop] - b[prop] : a[prop] < b[prop];
    arr.sort(sorter);
    return arr; 
});

const html = env.renderString(
    `{% for item in items | sortBy('block') %} 
        {{item.block}} {{ item.color}} 
    {% endfor %}`, 
    { 
        items: [
            { block: "1", color: 'Blue' },
            { block: "7", color: 'Green' },
            { block: "3", color: 'Yellow' }
        ]
    }
);

console.log(html);
```